# Xcode 11 not stopping on assert fail

Tags: xcode, assert

I am new to Xcode, so my apologies if there's a simple answer I've missed.

I converted an existing project, built using Swift and Objective C from Swift 3 to Swift 5 under Xcode 11.6

When I run under the debugger, I am seeing a series of assert fails:

> Cannot be called with asCopy = NO on non-main thread.

I understand that this means that UI calls are being made from background threads, but I don't know where the asserts are coming from.  Everything I can find online implies that Xcode should stop on an assert fail, but it's not doing so.

I am building for Run with Build Configuration Debug.  Debug executable is checked.  I have created an Exception breakpoint which shows as All Objective-C Exceptions.  I have turned on Main Thread Checker.

Yet, I see the asserts logged, but Xcode doesn't stop.

Is there a way to make Xcode break on these assert fails?  If not, what is the best method to find where they are happening.  I had thought that Main Thread Checker should have tripped on them as well.

Comment: You might be creating a UIAlertController on a background thread.

Comment: Not sure that that is all that is going on, but that is definitely happening, thank you

Comment: Yes, it's annoying that it logs without properly throwing the exception. But every case of this that I've been able to find has been caused ultimately by a UIAlertController being created on a background thread.